# How can I combine multiple Excel files and skip the first 6 rows of each file in R?

Tags: r, excel, rows, skip

I have 103 .xlsx files in one folder with one sheet each. I want to combine them in one file via R and skip the first 6 rows of each file (junk information). Have tried different approaches but nothing worked.

```
rm(list = ls())

library(readxl)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)

path = "X:/....."
setwd(path)

my_files <- list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx") 
my_files

age = lapply(my_files, function(i){
  x = read_excel(i, sheet=1)
  
  x$file = i
  
  x
})
age
```

I get this error message:

" New names:

- `` -> ...3
- `` -> ...4
- `` -> ...5
- `` -> ...6
- `` -> ...7
- ... and 20 more problems"

Comment: Please show us at least one approach you tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
files = list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")

df = list()
for (i in files){
      df = append(df, list(as.data.frame(read_excel(i))))
    }

df2 = data.frame()

for(i in 1:length(df)){
      df2 = rbind.data.frame(df2,df[[i]][-c(1:6),])
   }
```

Hi i have tested this on my dummy dataset. This code is working.It might help

Comment: Thank you. I get the same error messages with your approach. Could it be caused by the size of the files? These are quite big datasets.

Comment: Are the columns same in all the excel files?